# File I/O Confusion

Tags: java, file-io

First question here on StackOverflow, so apologies if this is bad. But I got a student job programming for civil engineers. My first assignment is to use JFileChooser to allow the user to specify a desired file, and then the full path of this file will be written to a txt file. I want it to automatically write to the file that this program using JFileChooser resides in. I am very confused on how to do this and haven't been able to find anything helpful on that.

My code:

```
public class FilePathFinder {
    JFileChooser fileChooser;

    String path;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String path = null; //String that will be outputted to 

        //creates file chooser and its properties
        JFileChooser file_chooser = new JFileChooser();
        file_chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("user.home"));
        file_chooser.setDialogTitle("Create File Path");
        file_chooser.setApproveButtonText("Create Path");
        file_chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        file_chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

        if (file_chooser.showOpenDialog(null)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            path=(file_chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        }

        //Writes path name to file
        String user_home_folder = System.getProperty("user.home");
        System.out.println(user_home_folder);
        File path_file = new File(user_home_folder, path);
        BufferedWriter path_writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path_file));
        if(!path_file.exists()){
            path_writer.write(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To make it easier for answerers, or others with similar problems, please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is the problem you are actually having?

A comment:

```
file_chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("user.home"));
```

This won't set the current directory to be the users home directory. But to a directory (if it exists) named "user.home" in the current directory. What you probably wanted to do is:

```
file_chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
```

**Update** By reading your comment on this answer:

You already have an absolute path in your variable `path`. But using the constructor `new File(user_home_folder, path)` your prefixing it with the location of the user's home directory. This results in a path like that has for example the drive letter twice in it. Remove the first parameter of this constructor.

Comment: Ok, that moved the FileChooser object to the right directory. But it is still throwing a FileNotFoundException at the line: BufferedWriter path_writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path_file));

Comment: @theo_the_NOVICE your previous comment was more helpful. The message of the FileNotFoundException told you which file could not be found. This file could not be found because the path to the file was incorrect. (As I explaned in my update to the answer.)

Comment: Ok thank you sorry for being vague still learning how to ask questions well. It executes fine now thank you!